# Swagger method to show attributes requirements

Tags: php, swagger

I am new to Swagger and am trying to understand how define which model attributes are required and some that should not be sent for each action.

For example, when registering a user attributes `first_name`,`last_name`,`email` and `password` are required. However these aren't required when updating other attributes. Also, some attributes should never be sent such as `role`.

I currently have this:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Post(
 *   path="/user/register",
 *   summary="Registers a new user",
 *   consumes={"application/json"},
 *   required={"first_name","last_name"},
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="User",
 *     description="User attributes",
 *     in="body",
 *     required=true,
 *     type="string",
 *     @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/User")
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="User object",
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *       @SWG\Items(ref="#definitions/User")
 *     )
 *   )
 * )
 */
```

I would like to add something like:

```
required={"first_name","last_name","email","password"},
ignore={"role","registration_date","status"},
```

Are these things possible?